# Tiger VNC Creating Session On loopback ip address

Tags: vnc, vnc-server

installed TigerVNC on Centos 8.3 and tried to run it with vncserver Command but it is giving me this message "vncserver has been replaced by a systemd unit."

I have also followed the instruction from this file /usr/share/doc/tigervnc/HOWTO.md and created a vnc session. the session is accessible only on loopback ip of the machine.

Result of : netstat -tulpn Command:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5905          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2645/Xvnc
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5905                :::*                    LISTEN      2645/Xvnc

how can i change loopback ip of vnc session to machine ip.

Answer (score 0):

Minhaj:

I ran into this today. TigerVNC has been changed with the version 8.x Fedora kernel. I dug a bit & found it is related to "an upstream decision." What this means in simple English is that the project team made a design decision. I personally agree with the design changes since it brings greater control and security to VCN than previous versions. This is not to suggest the actual VNC protocol is SSL enabled. You should still employ best practices like using firewalld to prevent access to VCN ports and using SSH tunneling to get to the console, etc.

To get started, you'll need to do a bit of simple configuration work as described in /usr/share/doc/tigervnc/HOWTO.md. Start by reading the instructions in the file.

All tasks must be run with root priv, so use the sudo utility for all of them.

TASK 1: At the simplest level, begin by opening the file /etc/tigervnc/vncserver.users

Create an entry for each user that will use the service. For example:

```
:1=hwojteczko
:2=esong
```

Note the digit preceding each user name. This is the VNC console number that will be assigned to each user. Save the file.

TASK 2: Inspect the /usr/share/xsessions file to confirm the type of desktop installed on the system. The default desktop is gnome, but there are others, so be mindful of this.

TASK 3: Next, you'll need to modify the Xvnc options file. Fortunately, there are some commented entries already left in place, which can be removed. Open the file /etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-defaults, remove the comments as shown below, but also add the desktop to the session config within the stanza. This will not likely be there, so it is easy to miss this step. See example below:

```
securitytypes=vncauth,tlsvnc
desktop=sandbox
geometry=2000x1200
localhost
alwaysshared
session=gnome
```

TASK 4: As the user, set a VNC password using vncpasswd  . This will be similar to what you are accustomed to with previous versions of TigerVNC, but it WILL NOT start TigerVNC.

IMPORTANT: For the next task, you must make sure that you, or the user, is not logged into a desktop session. For those like me who develop code on Linux, this is an easy way to get tripped up. This is not a concern if you are accessing a remote server.

TASK 5: Start the VNC Service for the correct user session. See below:

```
systemctl start vncserver@:1
```

You'll see there is no output to speak of. Use sysctl and check the status. It is best to wait about 10-15 seconds before doing so to ensure the startup does not fail.

```
systemctl status vncserver@:1
```

TASK 6: Now, you can check to see that port 5901 is open with nmap, as in:

```
nmap -PN localhost
```

Which should report something like:

PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
631/tcp  open  ipp
5901/tcp open  vnc-1

now you can ssh to the host and tunnel VNC traffic securely, such as:

```
ssh hwojteczko@172.16.129.5 -N -L localhost:5901:localhost:5901
```

TASK 7: When you are done, don't forget to shutdown TigerVCN using systemctl, as in:

```
systemctl stop vncserver@:1
```

Happy coding......

- h

Comment: thanks for reply, But how I'm going to access a graphical session of VNC from another device when it is Listening on localhost